# Evaluate integral using mapping

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Given $D = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 2 \ge x^2 + y^2 \ge 1 , x \ge y \ge -x\}$ and let $(u, v) = G(x, y) = (x^{2} + y^{2}, 2\cdot x \cdot y)$.

Evaluate

> $$\iint\limits_D (x^2 - y^2) \cos\left(\frac{\pi xy}{x^2 + y^2}\right) dA$$ using this given mapping.

I end up getting the integral

$$\frac{1}{4} \cdot \int_{-2}^{2} \int_{1}^{2} \cos(\frac{\pi v}{2 u}) dudv$$

Using change of variables

But how do I evaluate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add $u$ and $v$ together, you'll get
$$u+v=x^2+y^2+2xy=(x+y)^2.$$
Since $x+y\ge0$ due to the given constraint $y\ge-x$, we can take the square root, so
$$x+y=\sqrt{u+v}.$$
Similarly, if you subtract them, you'll get
$$u-v=x^2+y^2-2xy=(x-y)^2.$$
Again, since $x-y\ge0$ due to the given constraint $x\ge y$, we can take the square root, so
$$x-y=\sqrt{u-v}.$$

Now you can solve the system of equations
$$\left\{\begin{align} x+y&=\sqrt{u+v} \\ x-y&=\sqrt{u-v} \end{align}\right.$$

---

**UPDATE:** now that the change of variable issue has been resolved, and we need to finish integration of the new double integral.

Your limits of integration for $v$ are incorrect. If you graph the region, you'll see that in the $(u,v)$-plane it's not going to be a rectangular region, and the limits of integration for $v$ are not from $-2$ to $2$ (even though these actually are its least and greatest values). Here are the correct constraints and how we can find them.

- From $y\le x$, we have an "upper" boundary given by
  $$y=x \; \Rightarrow \; x-y=0 \; \Rightarrow \; \sqrt{u-v}=0 \; \Rightarrow \; u-v=0 \; \Rightarrow \; v=u.$$
- From $-x\le y$, we have a "lower" boundary given by
  $$y=-x \; \Rightarrow \; x+y=0 \; \Rightarrow \; \sqrt{u+v}=0 \; \Rightarrow \; u+v=0 \; \Rightarrow \; v=-u.$$

So $v$ ranges within $-u\le v\le u$ (reaching the values of $-2$ and $2$ only when $u=2$). And the correct double integral is
$$\frac{1}{4} \cdot \int_1^2 \int_{-u}^u \cos\left(\frac{\pi v}{2u}\right)\,dv\,du.$$

I hope you can take it from here. The inside integral is now with respect to $v$, which is actually doable.

Comment: I got this, but how do I proceed with the integral? I multiplied by the jacbonian, but its really confusing still

Comment: @Bana: Well, that's a whole other question! Your post above only asked for help with the inverse map.

Comment: @Bana: Changing a question into a completely different one is not too nice. You could've added more, as an update to the question -- that's a much better option.

Comment: Read the title of the question. I asked for hints, but the whole point was to solve the integral.

Comment: @Bana: First of all, your original question (which is not available anymore because you've completely rewritten it) clearly asked about hints for the substitution only. If you had something else in mind -- that's understandable, but how are we supposed to know what's in your mind if it wasn't what you wrote here? Second, are you sure it's a good idea being rude to people who are taking there time to try to help you for free? Sorry, but I don't owe you anything, so you don't get to order me around requiring to "read the title of the question".

Comment: Ok, im sorry. How can I rollback?

Comment: @Bana: About rolling back -- to be honest, I don't know, As for integration, please see the update in my answer above.

Comment: I'm sorry man, like I didn't mean whatever I said. When I was reading it myself I didn't think you would be offended, that wasn't my intention. I also admit its my fault for changing in the middle and thinking you will know what I meant, which is my bad.



Thanks so much for answering, it all helps and I apologize. I appreciate every bit of help I get here

Comment: @Bana: No worries, and you're welcome!