# Find the image under the function map

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

> Let $D = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | 1 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 2, -x \le y \le x \}$ and let $(u, v) = F(x, y) = (x^2 + y^2, 2xy)$. Find the image of $D$ under the mapping $F$

I am seriously confused and unable to get this.

If I use polar coordinates, I get

$(u, v) = (r^2, 2r^2\sin(2\theta))$ using polar coordinates.

From the constraints of $D$, I get $1 \le r^2 \le 2$ and $-1 \le \sin(2\theta) \le 1$

So I should have

$-2 \le r\sin(2\theta) \le 2$?

So is the correct answer

> $1 \le u \le 2$
>
> $-2 \le v \le 2$

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{array}{rlll}F(D)~&=~\{(x^2+y^2, 2xy) &: 1\leq x^2+y^2\leq 2,& -x\leq y\leq x&\}
\\ &=~ \{(r^2, 2r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta) &: 1\leq r^2\leq 2,& -r\cos\theta\leq r\sin\theta\leq r\cos\theta, -\pi\leq 2\theta\leq \pi&\}
\\ &=~ \{(r^2, r^2\sin2\theta) &: 1\leq r^2\leq 2,& \sin^2\theta\leq \cos^2\theta, -\pi\leq 2\theta\leq \pi&\}
\\ &=~ \{(r^2, r^2\sin2\theta)&: 1\leq r^2\leq 2,& 2\sin^2\theta\leq 1, -\pi\leq 2\theta\leq \pi&\}
\\ &=~ \{(r^2, r^2\sin2\theta)&: 1\leq r^2\leq 2,& -\arcsin2^{-1/2}\leq\theta\leq \arcsin2^{-1/2}&\}
\\ &=~ \{(r^2, r^2\sin2\theta)&: 1\leq r^2\leq 2,& -\sin(2\arcsin2^{-1/2})\leq\sin 2\theta\leq \sin(2\arcsin2^{-1/2})&\}
\\ &=~ \{(u, uw)&: 1\leq u\leq 2,& -1\leq w\leq 1&\}
\\ &=~ \{(u, v)&: 1\leq u\leq 2,& -u\leq v\leq u&\}
\end{array}$

Answer (score 0):

Put $a = x+y, b = x - y$, the inequalities on the right imply that: $a \ge 0, b \ge 0$, and $x^2+y^2 = \dfrac{(x-y)^2+(x+y)^2}{2}= \dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}, 2xy = \dfrac{(x+y)^2 - (x-y)^2}{2}= \dfrac{a^2-b^2}{2}$. Thus $1 \le x^2+y^2 \le 2$ translates to $ 2 \le a^2+b^2 \le 4\implies 1 \le \dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2} \le 2, \dfrac{a^2-b^2}{2} = \dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}-b^2 \le \dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2} \le 2$. Also $\dfrac{a^2-b^2}{2}\ge -\dfrac{b^2}{2}\ge -\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}\ge -2$. From these inequalities you deduce that: $F(D)= \{(u,v): 1 \le u \le 2, -2 \le v \le 2\}$ as claimed.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2382021/evaluate-integral-using-mapping, Then why do I get the wrong answer with this integral? It must be an error in the bounds right?